On the Relationship Between Graph Isomorphism and Equivalence in ETL Workflow Dependency Graphs
Let $G = (V, E)$ and $G' = (V', E')$ be two DAGs representing dependency graphs of ETL workflows. Each node $v \in V$ (or $v' \in V'$) represents a task, which is a tuple $t_v = (q_v, d_v, s_v)$, where:

$q_v: D_{in}(v) \to D_{out}(v)$ is a function representing the computation performed by the task, mapping input data to output data,
$d_v \subseteq D_{in}(v)$ is the set of input data required by the task, and
$s_v \subseteq D_{out}(v)$ is the set of output data produced by the task.

Here, $D_{in}(v)$ and $D_{out}(v)$ denote the input and output data domains for task $v$, respectively.
The edges $E \subseteq V \times V$ (or $E' \subseteq V' \times V'$) represent task dependencies, where $(u, v) \in E$ iff the output of task $u$ is required as input for task $v$.
An equivalence relation $\sim$ on the set of all DAGs can be defined as follows:
$G \sim G'$ iff, given the same input data and initial external states, the execution of the workflows represented by $G$ and $G'$ produces the same output data and final external states.
An isomorphism between $G$ and $G'$ is a bijective function $\varphi: V \to V'$ such that:

$(u, v) \in E \iff (\varphi(u), \varphi(v)) \in E'$, and
$t_u = t_{\varphi(u)}$ for all $u \in V$.

A potential counterexample demonstrates that graph isomorphism does not necessarily imply workflow equivalence. Consider two DAGs $G = (V, E)$ and $G' = (V', E')$ with tasks:

$t_1: (\pi_P, \emptyset, \{d_1\})$, where $\pi_P$ is a projection on predicate $P$,
$t_2: (f, \{d_1\}, \{d_2\})$, where $f$ is a transformation function,
$t_3: (g, \{d_1\}, \{d_3\})$, where $g$ is a transformation function,
$t_4: (\bowtie_h, \{d_2, d_3\}, \{d_4\})$, where $\bowtie_h$ is a join on condition $h$,
$t_5: (\mathrm{id}, \{d_4\}, \emptyset)$, where $\mathrm{id}$ is the identity function (load operation).

Let $V = V' = \{t_1, t_2, t_3, t_4, t_5\}$, $E = \{(t_1, t_2), (t_1, t_3), (t_2, t_4), (t_3, t_4), (t_4, t_5)\}$, and $E' = \{(t_1, t_2), (t_1, t_3), (t_2, t_4), (t_3, t_5), (t_4, t_5)\}$.
The identity function $\varphi: V \to V'$ is an isomorphism between $G$ and $G'$. However, if the join condition $h$ is not commutative, the execution of the workflows may produce different output data, implying $G \nsim G'$.
Here is a potentially practical counterexample:
Suppose we have two ETL workflows for processing customer data in an e-commerce company. The workflows are represented by DAGs $G$ and $G'$ with the following tasks:
$G$:
$t_1: (\mathrm{extractCustomerData}, \emptyset, {\mathrm{rawData}})$, where $\mathrm{extractCustomerData}$ reads customer data from a source (e.g., a database) and produces $\mathrm{rawData}$.
$t_2: (\mathrm{cleanData}, {\mathrm{rawData}}, {\mathrm{cleanedData}})$, where $\mathrm{cleanData}$ applies data cleaning operations (e.g., removing duplicates, handling missing values) to $\mathrm{rawData}$ and produces $\mathrm{cleanedData}$.
$t_3: (\mathrm{transformData}, {\mathrm{cleanedData}}, {\mathrm{transformedData}})$, where $\mathrm{transformData}$ applies business logic and transformations (e.g., calculating customer lifetime value) to $\mathrm{cleanedData}$ and produces $\mathrm{transformedData}$.
$t_4: (\mathrm{loadData}, {\mathrm{transformedData}}, \emptyset)$, where $\mathrm{loadData}$ writes $\mathrm{transformedData}$ to a target system (e.g., a data warehouse).
$G'$:
$t_1': (\mathrm{extractCustomerData}, \emptyset, {\mathrm{rawData}'})$, where $\mathrm{extractCustomerData}$ reads customer data from the same source as in $G$ and produces $\mathrm{rawData}'$.
$t_2': (\mathrm{cleanData}, {\mathrm{rawData}'}, {\mathrm{cleanedData}'})$, where $\mathrm{cleanData}$ applies the same data cleaning operations as in $G$ to $\mathrm{rawData}'$ and produces $\mathrm{cleanedData}'$.
$t_3': (\mathrm{loadData}, {\mathrm{cleanedData}'}, \emptyset)$, where $\mathrm{loadData}$ writes $\mathrm{cleanedData}'$ directly to the target system, skipping the data transformation step.
In this example, both workflows start with extracting raw customer data, followed by a data cleaning step. However, $G$ applies an additional data transformation step before loading the data, while $G'$ loads the cleaned data directly without any transformations.
The main question is whether these two workflows are equivalent, i.e., whether they produce the same output data and final external states, given the same input data and initial external states. The workflows have the same structure (isomorphic graphs) but differ in the presence of the data transformation step.
Questions:

Under what conditions does isomorphism imply equivalence, assuming deterministic tasks and inaccessible input data? Is there another notion of "isomorphism" that can guarantee equivalence?
Is there an efficient algorithm to determine if two DAGs are equivalent? What is its complexity?
How do task commutativity and idempotence impact the equivalence relation $\sim$? Can the equivalence classes induced by $\sim$ under these properties be characterized?

References to relevant literature that could help address these questions would be greatly appreciated. I don't want to always have to create fake data to test if my code is correct.

I'm not sure I understand how you are defining a graph isomorphism. In the first example, how is $\varphi$ an isomorphism if $(t_3, t_4)$ is an edge in $G$ but not in $G'$? In fact, $t_4$ has in-degree 2 in $G$ but in-degree 1 in $G'$; in what sense are these graphs isomorphic? In the second example, how are the workflows $G$ and $G'$ isomorphic if the former has 4 steps and the latter has 3 steps?
